# get current Position with html and use it with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation

I'd like to get my current position with HTML5 and use it with javascript.
I did some test, it works, but with my final version I have an `undefined` value.

```
function geolocError(dueToBrowser=true){
    if(dueToBrowser){
        alert('your browser does not support HTML5 geolocation');
    }else{
        alert('error with geolocation');
    }   
}



function getPositon(){
    return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        return position.coords;
    }, geolocError);
}

$(document).ready(function() {



    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        var pos = getPositon();

        console.log(pos)
}
});
```

My `console.log(pos);` returns me `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geolocation is async, you cannot do that. You should set logic in getCurrentPosition callback or use a deferred object:

See e.g [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7n66/)

```
var defer = $.Deferred();

function getPositon() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        defer.resolveWith(position.coords);
    }, geolocError);
    return defer;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        getPositon().done(function () {
            console.log(this);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks it works but it's a bad new. I had as idea to have the position on each page when it's loaded. For example i would like to post a comment with my position but i don't want the user wait to post it request :( it is a solution to store to position in a cookie ?

Comment: I've used sessionStorage instead of cookie